# Is it possible to check the length of two strings before pattern matching against them?

Tags: pattern-matching, coq

I'm programming in Coq and want to eliminate non-exhaustive case matching by checking the length of the  two strings first, for example

```ml
Definition foo (word1 word2 : word) : option :=
    if length word1 =? length word2 then
    * pattern matching logic that only concerns same length word patterns *
    else None.
```

I still get a non-exhaustive pattern matching error. Is it possible for m to do this or do I have to approach my function in another way?

Comment: I am not sure many will understand "non-exhaustive case matching". So it might be useful to add some sample strings which clarify what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

There is always the option to add a wildcard match statement at the end to suppress that error. Assuming, you can transfer this from ocaml to coq, here is what I mean:

```ml
let foo x y =
    if String.length x = String.length y
    then
       match (x,y) with
       | ("foo","bar") -> Some true
       | _ -> None
    else
       None
```

When using the wildcard, you can remove the surrounding if, of course, because the wildcard case also catches different length strings.

Comment: @monique I second that. Moreover, note that only exhaustive pattern matching exists in Coq. It is possible to write some functions without explicitly covering all the cases, but this is only syntax sugar -- internally, Coq still produces an exhaustive match.